# Missing IOManager in Akka 2.3.6

Tags: java, scala, migration, akka

Hi I searched the documentation and the migration page, but I was not able to find the replacement or a explanation what actually happened to IOManager since akka 2.2.4?!

Any help appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I believe that using the `IOManager` directly was deprecated at some point in `2.2`.  If you look at the scala docs for that class all of the methods instruct you to use the new system in the `akka.io` package.  I believe they went this way to give you the ability to use I/O with different protocols (TCP, UDP) by passing the right extension into the `akka.io.IO.apply` method.

Comment: I added as an answer.  Please accept it if you believe it is the correct answer to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that using the `IOManager` directly was deprecated at some point in 2.2. If you look at the scala docs for that class all of the methods instruct you to use the new system in the `akka.io` package. I believe they went this way to give you the ability to use I/O with different protocols (TCP, UDP) by passing the right extension into the `akka.io.IO.apply`